# Global traffic policy within same region

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, istio, network-traffic, istio-gateway

Scenario for multi controlplane
When I have two clusters in same region.I have admiral on one of the cluster.Created global traffic policy,in which ilbtype is 0.

I don't see any service entries created between them.So traffic policy will not work for applications deployed on 2clsuters within same region and zone.??

Gtp within same region and zone is possible or not?

Comment: Refer to this [Blog](https://www.infracloud.io/blogs/simplify-multi-cluster-istio-service-mesh-using-admiral/) by Infra cloud The Global Traffic Policy can be created in any of the clusters the Admiral is watching over.

Comment: It works on the identity label and annotations to generate a globally unique DNS name for all the services having the matching label

Comment: Refer to this official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones)  In GCP Regional resources can be used by any resource in that region, regardless of zone, while zonal resources can only be used by other resources in the same zone.

Comment: Have you checked my comments

Comment: Thanks @ Sai chandini, I have added identity to the application deployment yaml.Still I don't see any service entry created to admiral-sync folder.I don't see any error logs regarding this. What might be missing any guess?

Comment: Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/22605) related to your issue